# How to find module in truffle pack

Tags: truffle, javascript

I am trying to run a JS test script with truffles but I can not seem to find the right place to store the `assertRevert` file so that the module can be found by the script when I try to run the test.

```
const { assertRevert } = require('assertRevert');
```

Is that the top of my script.

The Error I am getting is `Cannot find module 'assertRevert'`

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try `require('assertRevert.js')`, otherwise, node searches in its own installation path rather than in your local path.

Comment: Still not working. Where would you store the file in the test folder or main directory of the project ?

Comment: Sorry, try `require('./assertRevert.js')`. Of course, if the file `assertRevert.js` is not located in the same path as your script, then use the correct relative path instead of `./`.

Comment: Still no luck, any other ideas what could be going wrong ? The assetRevert file is in my test folder and still getting no luck.

Comment: Do you properly export in that file? i.e., do you assign `module.exports = ...` somewhere? Also, why exactly do you do `const { assertRevert } = ...` with those curly braces? Seems like you're not entirely familiar with how to export JS code properly. There's a lot of information on that, and you probably want to search it on Stack Overflow, because it doesn't have anything to do specifically with Ethereum.

Comment: Yes here is the code 

`module.exports = {
  assertRevert: async (promise) => {
    try {
      await promise;
    } catch (error) {
      const revertFound = error.message.search('revert') >= 0;
      assert(revertFound, `Expected "revert", got ${error} instead`);
      return;
    }
    assert.fail('Expected revert not received');
  },
};`


And I copied the code from the open zeppelin erc20 testing source code.

Comment: So you should do `const assertRevert = require('./assertRevert.js').assertRevert;`.

Comment: Thanks for you help mate, its greatly appreciated ! I ended up creating a helpers folder within the project directory. 

The final piece of code that worked is const assertRevert = require('../helpers/assertRevert.js').assertRevert;

Comment: You're welcome. If you're looking for a cleaner way to catch exceptions in your tests, then you can check out [this answer of mine](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/48629/16043) on a related question.