# Revert not throwing error when running truffle test

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, private-blockchain, truffle-test

I have set up a local geth on ubuntu and I'm running my project on it.

While writing test cases, I saw that the test cases which were working fine in testrpc environment started facing issues when run on local geth developement environment.

I don't get any error message from my test case when revert() is caught in my solidity code.

Here the example:

```
myContract {
   function ExpectedARevertWhenCalled(){
       revert();
   }
}
```

---

Now when I call this method in my test. The test cases should fail but no error is thrown.

Can someone please help understand the issue behind it?

**FYI:** This is how I'm calling the method in my test case:

```
contract('MyContract', async () => {
  it("myContractFunction", async () => {
    let obj= await TwoKeyReg.new();
    await obj.ExpectedARevertWhenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't know why it's not throwing, but you can try `require(false);` instead of `revert();`

Comment: What is your test code?

Comment: Hi Raghav, kindly have a look at the code. I have added the test code as asked. I can assure you there's no problem with the code as I have been working with it very fine in ganache/testrpc environment.

Comment: Hey Maxpeinas. Solidity code is working fine. The revert() is doing what it has to do. The problem is when I run the test cases. I wonder why test cases aren't failing when revert is read in private blockchain setup. On the other hand, same test cases failed when run with testrpc! :/

Comment: test case pass/failed depends on your assert/expected result, not from the actual result.

Answer (score 1):

If your test goal is expecting a revert() then you should do as following

Use revert helper method from openzepplin, named `assertRevert.js`

```
module.exports = async promise => {
  try {
    await promise;
    assert.fail('Expected revert not received');
  } catch (error) {
    const revertFound = error.message.search('revert') >= 0;
    assert(revertFound, `Expected "revert", got ${error} instead`);
  }
};
```

Import the revert to your test code

```
const assertRevert = require('assertRevert');
```

Then make your test code like below, mean that you expecting the method to throw a revert

```
contract('MyContract', async () => {
  it("myContractFunction", async () => {
    let obj= await TwoKeyReg.new();
    await assertRevert(obj.ExpectedARevertWhenCalled());
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi. I have implemented the solution given here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48627/how-to-catch-revert-error-in-truffle-test-javascript to catch revert type error in assert. It works quiet well with testrpc but when I ran the same code in my local-geth network, it throws an AssertionError saying "Expected an error but did not get one". This means I'm not at all receiving any kind of error from revert.

Comment: when running on the local-geth, it might be that another error happen before reaching the revert; then we only know exactly if you provide fully code and your local environment setup