# How to catch a `revert()` error using Brownie?

Tags: revert-opcode, brownie

I am using [Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io) to develop my smart contracts, which helps me to intract with the smart contracts, please see [doc](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interaction.html).

When my call `Example.greet()` is there any way to return the error message and act based on it during my tests? Also find out is it reverted because the transaction is out of gas or not.

Similar question is answered for Truffle: [[how to catch “revert” error in truffle test javascript?]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48627/how-to-catch-revert-error-in-truffle-test-javascript).

---

Example of a simple contract with a `revert()` message:

```
contract Example{
    function greet(){
        revert("Hello World");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Same question is already asked for Truffle also [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/48627/16043), and this one does have an answer. Does it help?

Comment: Sorry I did not see the other answer an updated my question based on that.

Comment: NP, feel free to edit the answer and change `deployed` in the 3rd line to `invoked` :)

Comment: Done, I also mark duplicated for the question I linked before to your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`brownie.reverts`](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-test.html#brownie.test.plugin.RevertContextManager) context manager handles exactly this use case. The syntax is very similar to [`pytest.raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest.raises):

```py
import brownie

def test_greet(example):
    with brownie.reverts("Hello World"):
         example.greet()
```

Including the error string is optional, if you omit it you can catch any revert regardless of the message returned.

- Source: Brownie documentation - [Handling Reverted Transactions](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests-pytest-intro.html#handling-reverted-transactions)

Comment: Does it also catch if the transaction is reverted because of out of gas issue?

Comment: Also if my `revert()` function is without a message but commented next to it to save some gas like: `revert(); // dev: Hello World`, can it also catch the error message (even it is commented out)?

Comment: @alper I've answered your second question here - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84259/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-dev-comment-after-a-revert-or-require-statement/84260#84260

Comment: For out of gas, the error string will be "out of gas"