# What is the purpose of a `// dev:` comment after a revert or require statement?

Tags: solidity, revert-opcode, brownie

What does it mean when a Solidity contract includes a comment starting with `// dev:` after a revert or require statement?

For example:

```
contract Example {
    function greet(){
        revert(); // dev: Hello World        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a **developer revert comment**. From the [Brownie documentation](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests-pytest-intro.html#developer-revert-comments):

> Each revert string adds a minimum 20000 gas to your contract deployment cost, and increases the cost for a function to execute. Including a revert string for every `require` and `revert` statement is often impractical and sometimes simply not possible due to the block gas limit.
>
> For this reason, Brownie allows you to include revert strings as source code comments that are not included in the bytecode but still accessible via `TransactionReceipt.revert_msg`. You write tests that target a specific `require` or `revert` statement without increasing gas costs.

To write a test that handles the example in the question, use the entire revert comment starting with `dev`:

```py
import brownie

def test_greet(example):
    with brownie.reverts("dev: Hello World"):
         example.greet()
```

For more information:

- [Efficient Smart Contract Testing: Developer Revert Comments](https://medium.com/coinmonks/effective-smart-contract-testing-developer-revert-comments-c7a6f250df0f)

Disclosure: I am the lead developer for Brownie.

Comment: This answer would make a great example within the docs =)